# AFNetworking swift JSON AnyObject casting

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

In result of AFNetworking response I got AnyObject dictionary like structure, which is not casting as Dictionary and fails with error.
So I've used structure as following

```
if let data: AnyObject = responseObject["data"]! {
                if let current_condition: AnyObject = data["current_condition"]! {
                    print(current_condition.valueForKey("FeelsLikeC")!)
                }
            }
```

That gave me some result which I can't cast as anything and in output it looks like this

```
(
9
)
```

How do I cast it as Int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's an array

```
if let arr = current_condition.valueForKey("FeelsLikeC") as? NSArray {
      print(arr[0])
}
```